# How to create template filters that don't change original value

Tags: python, django-templates, jinja2, django-template-filters

I'd like to create filters that don't change the original value of the variable to which they are applied.

Here is a very simple filter:

```
def increment(mynumber):
    return mynumber + 1

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.filters['increment'] = increment
```

If in the template I have something like:

```
{% set anumber = 10 %}
<span>first: {{ anumber|increment }}</span>
<span>second: {{ anumber|increment }}</span>
```

I would expect to see displayed:

```
first: 11
second: 11
```

and instead I get:

```
first: 11
second: 12
```

How can I achieve the first type result?
Can I also do it so that chained filters will pass the new value along?
For example:

```
<span>first: {{ anumber|increment|increment|increment }}</span>
<span>second: {{ anumber|increment }}</span>
```

will output

```
first: 13
second: 11
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm really sorry, I didn't know that in python variables are assigned by reference and not by value. And my example was too simple: I'm actually dealing with dictionaries.

The solution is as simple as:

```
def myFilter(myDict):
    returnDict = myDict.copy()
    # change returnDict ..
    return returnDict
```